# How can I find what type of encryption my DMG is using?

Tags: macos, encryption, disk-encryption, dmg-image

I have an encrypted DMG file on my Mac. Is there any way to use Terminal, and maybe the `diskutil` command to list what type of encryption the DMG is using? Or perhaps some other command? Or maybe there's an even simpler way of doing this using Finder only?

Comment: `diskutil info` maybe? I can't check now. Why would you need to know?

Comment: I didn't find any way to see the type of encryption (like AES-128 or AES-256), but after you have mounted a disk image, `hdiutil info` displays `image-encrypted : TRUE` if the disk image is encrypted.